# How to grep a string vector in another string vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have two string vectors:

```
s1<-c("ab", "cd-e", "hij")
s2<-c("0ab12345", "xyzcd-e", "uvwxyz132", "13216469", "%qrst012")
```

what I wanted is to find the items in `s1` that appear in `s2` thus the above example   will give an output

```
"ab", "cd-e"
```

Comment: Try `unlist(lapply(s1, function(x) s1[grep(x, s2)]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Filter` with the indicated function.  No packages are used.

```
Filter(function(x) any(grepl(x, s2)), s1)
## [1] "ab"   "cd-e"
```

Comment: Or with `keep` from `purrr` `keep(s1, ~ any(grepl(.x, s2)))`

Answer (score 2):

We can `grepl` over s1 for every value in `s2` and select if any of them is `TRUE`.

```
s1[colSums(sapply(s1, grepl, s2)) > 0]
#[1] "ab"   "cd-e"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
s1[sapply(s1,function(x) any(grepl(x,s2)))]
[1] "ab"   "cd-e
```